# get all values from a key in a dictionary object

Tags: javascript, key, key-value

I have a dictionary, how do I get the values of a specified key?

```
var dic = {};
dic["asdf"] = 1;
dic["bnm"] = 2;
console.log(dic["asdf"]);
```

Comment: You already got that correct.

Comment: some reason it wasn't working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dic = {'asdf': 1 , 'bnm': 2};
dic['xyz']=3;
console.log(dic['asdf']);
console.log(dic['xyz']);
```